# Why can't array elements use push methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
var strArr = []
strArr[0].push("someThing Text")
console.log(strArr)
```

Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

```js
var strArr = []
strArr[0] = "someThing Text"
console.log(strArr)
```

Array ["someThing Text"]

What's the difference between the two? Why can't array elements use push methods?

Comment: The array element would need to be of type array to have `.push()` defined on the element.

Comment: `strArr[0]` is `undefined`, which doesn’t have properties.

Comment: You should look over the documentation or push. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to push into an array at index 0 inside another array.

```js
var strArr = []
strArr.push("someThing Text")
console.log(strArr)
```

If you wanted your code to work, you would need to do this.

```js
var strArr = [ [] ] // an array in an array
strArr[0].push("someThing Text")
console.log(strArr)
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, `push` is an array method. that means it only applies to an array (I look forward to a correction as I am a learner too).

Therefore, `push` will only apply/operate on an array element if the element is an array as well. Another way to grasp this is to note that elements in an array may be of different data types. Each data type has a different (predefined) set of operations/methods that can be applied to them. `push` is a predefined method that can be applied only to an array or array element(s) that is/are of the type array.

See the snipped below:

```js
const myArr = ['Hello', 'World', ['Javascript', 'Python', 'PHP'], 100, 'function'];

console.log('Orginal array --> ' + myArr); // Orginal array: Hello,World,Javascript,Python,PHP,100,function
myArr.push(['Vue', 'Angular', 'React']);
console.log('Updated array --> ' + myArr); // Updated array --> Hello,World,Javascript,Python,PHP,100,function,Vue,Angular,React
myArr[2].push('Java');
console.log('Update myArr[2] ' + myArr); // Update myArr[2] Hello,World,Javascript,Python,PHP,Java,100,function,Vue,Angular,React
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call an array function, you need to call it on the array itself, i.e. `strArr.push("someThing Text")`. `strArr[0]` is an array element, and could be a number, string, boolean, or other data type.

You can however add an array element at a specific point in an array, which is sort of what it looks like you were trying to do, with `Array.splice()`. The parameters are:

- index where array element should be inserted
- number of items (starting at index) you want to delete
- the actual elements you want to insert

```js
var strArr = ["foo", "bar"]
strArr.splice(1, 0, "someThing Text")
console.log(strArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the push method on an array element, not the array.
You should use strArr.push()

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add the element in a specific position using push() method. But the push() method is used to add one or multiple elements to the end of an array. An object can be inserted by passing the object as a parameter to this method. The object is hence added to the end of the array.

```
array.push(objectName)
```

```
var strArr = []
strArr.push("someThing Text")
console.log(strArr)
```